# Set nested dynamic keys over dynamic keys

Tags: javascript

Lets say I've got the following:

```js
  let key1 = 'firstkey'
  let key2 = 'secondkey'
  let obj = {}
```

Now I can set a key on `obj` using a dynamic key as:

```
  obj[key1]= 'randomvalue' // Equals to obj: { firstkey: 'randomvalue' }
```

there is a quick way of writing this:

```
  obj[key1][key2] = 'randomvalue' // Should equal to obj: { firstkey: { secondkey: 'randomvalue'} }
```

Without needing to previously check if the nested property `key1` actually exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1, using the spread operator

```js
let key1 = "firstkey";
let key2 = "secondkey";
let obj = {};

obj[key1] = { ...obj[key1], [key2]: "randomvalue" };
console.log(obj);
```

Option 2, use [Lodash.set](https://lodash.com/docs/#set)

```js
_.set(obj, [key1, key2], "randomvalue");
```